# Using regex with sed search and replace

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to remove some dynamic text from the log file. I am able to extract it using `regex` and `grep -oP`, however, the same regex is not working
with `sed` command.

Sample data: *(for reading convenience Concerned data between ABCDEF and LMNOP only)*

```
XXX  2 13:53:35 XXXX0-0-0 XXXXXXXX[3513]:  ABCDEF[XXXX]: 1472846015.555671: LMNOP(79): XXXXXXXXXXXXX - XXXXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXX XX XXXXX XXXX XXX XXXX XXX
```

Following is the data I want to remove from the log file. I am able to extract it using regex + `grep` :

```
grep -Po ']: [0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{6}:' sample
]: 1472846015.555671:
```

Now, if I use the same regex with `sed` command it's not helping.Any suggestions ?

I used the following command with sed and it returned me the unchanged file.

```
sed "s/]: [0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{6}://" input
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/]: [0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{6}:/,"")}1' input
```

I need following output:

```
XXX  2 13:53:35 XXXX0-0-0 XXXXXXXX[3513]:  ABCDEF[XXXX LMNOP(79): XXXXXXXXXXXXX - XXXXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXX XX XXXXX XXXX XXX XXXX XXX
```

OR even better :

```
XXX  2 13:53:35 XXXX0-0-0 XXXXXXXX[3513]:  ABCDEF[XXXX]::LMNOP(79): XXXXXXXXXXXXX - XXXXXX XX XXX XXX XXXXX XX XXXXX XXXX XXX XXXX XXX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into the `sed` use:

```
sed "s/]: [0-9]\{10\}\.[0-9]\{6\}: /]::/" input
```

#1 of the "s/#1/#2/" instruction searchs for the pattern, but you need to escape curly braces (`\{` and `\}`).  Then replace it to #2, which will add `]:` backward cause it is in the search pattern.  If you needs `::`, the add it into the replace pattern, like above.

But maybe you don't need to search and replace `]:`, just replace digits and dot to `:` with command (it works for your example)

```
sed "s/ [0-9]\{10\}\.[0-9]\{6\}: /:/" input
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use sed with extended regex. But note that the extended regex is a GNU extension and so may not be portable. Here is the same sed as suggested by @Konstantin Morenko, but without the backslashes for the `{` and `}`. Extended regex option is `-r` or `--regexp-extended`

```
sed -r "s/ [0-9]{10}\.[0-9]{6}: /:/" input
```